# What is the first time Wolverine cuts someone with his claws in a real way?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

After having read a lot of *X-Men* and 130-200+ and other spin-offs from that time, I had noticed that Wolverine never uses his claws on anyone if it would do real harm. Cut to modern day, and he is slicing people into ribbons.

In the old comic books we are always made to think that Wolverine has no scruples against using them as weapons, and does not care about killing his enemies.

This has made me wonder, what is the first time (in publication order) we see Wolverine use his claws for real?

Here are my rules:

- Wolverine must land a mortal blow, or remove an appendage;
- It has to be on a Marvel comic book;
- It has to be drawn in the panel;
- The victim must not be a robot, a zombie, or anything else weird that does not bleed;
- The victim can't have regeneration.

Let's say this image would count as a proper hit if it was first.

[image]

I would love to see the first panel as well as know in what series or year this change occurred.

Comment: Not in panel, and thus not a valid answer; however, we know that Wolverine at least maimed several of the Hellfire Club guards during the X-Men's first encounter with them circa (uncanny) *X-Men* 133; the guards became some of the cyborg Reavers.

Comment: There is a character called Kierrok the Damned, who is a demon adversary who shows up pretty early in the All-New X-Men line-up. He bleeds green, but is still a very brutal kill used to establish Wolverine as a badass not to be crossed. Does this encounter work for you?

Comment: I don't mind posting Kierrok as my answer, just want to make sure it fits your requirements.

Comment: @Gothamite24 I tried to find the related comic but I had problems figuring it out. I honestly don't know enough about Kierrok. If he is killed by being cut then it counts. I guess technically i did say "bleeds red:, but at this point I think it would be a good answer

Comment: Sounds good, I will try to find a panel depicting the scen

Comment: @Gothamite24 I did some digging, and I think you got the right one. wolverine debuted in October, 1974 and slays Kierrok in _Uncanny X-Men_ #96 (December 1975). [Here's the panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8tgv.jpg) you were thinking about, you can write your answer now :)

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the instance I was thinking of, I will post an answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Gothamite24's thinking with the demon Kierrok in the comments would be a solid contender.  Since it has lain fallow for these months, I'll "carpe diem")*

The first particularly gory example would be "X-Men" #96 in 1975.  I would wager Wolverine is allowed to "go nuts" because Kierrok is an alien demon thing with green ichor for blood.  Wouldn't offend delicate sensibilities or the rules protecting same. Also, it is established on the next page that Kierrok regenerates all this damage in very short order.

[image]

For "red blood" and more terrestrial victims of Wolverine's claws, I offer the following:

Magneto!  The panel sequence is from "X-Men" #113 in 1978.  It explains it all, as Wolverine "tags the man" and Magneto screams in pain.

[image]

The Savage Land indeed brought out the violence in Wolverine.  Soon after issue #113, there is this moment in #114 when a fastball special brought Wolverine in range of a giant pterasaur.  Poor beastie...

[image]

And then, #116 saw two instances.  The first is subtle, but even though it happens off-panel, there is no doubt Wolverine did not "knock the sentry unconscious".  Following that, a dinosaur gets a gooey lobotomy from a snikt.[image]

[image]